# wscript FTP download error

Tags: windows, vbscript, ftp

I am trying to use this vbs script by naterice.com. It seems working but downloaded files, or file are blank. Any idea? (Windows 2000, IIS6). Thanks.

```
DIM sSite
DIM sUsername
DIM sPassword
DIM sLocalPath
DIM sRemotePath
DIM sRemoteFile

sSite="xxx.xxx.xx"
sUsername="yyyy"
sPassword="password"
sLocalPath="C:\rss"
sRemotePath="/directory"
sRemoteFile="*.htm"

FTPDownload sSite, sUsername, sPassword, sLocalPath, sRemotePath, sRemoteFile

Function FTPDownload(sSite, sUsername, sPassword, sLocalPath, sRemotePath, sRemoteFile)
  'This script is provided under the Creative Commons license located
  'at http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/ . It may not
  'be used for commercial purposes with out the expressed written consent
  'of NateRice.com

  Const OpenAsDefault = -2
  Const FailIfNotExist = 0
  Const ForReading = 1
  Const ForWriting = 2

  Set oFTPScriptFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set oFTPScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  sRemotePath = Trim(sRemotePath)
  sLocalPath = Trim(sLocalPath)

  sOriginalWorkingDirectory = oFTPScriptShell.CurrentDirectory
  oFTPScriptShell.CurrentDirectory = sLocalPath
  '--------END Path Checks---------

  'build input file for ftp command
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "USER " & sUsername & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & sPassword & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "cd " & sRemotePath & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "binary" & vbCRLF
' sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "ascii" & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "prompt n" & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "mget " & sRemoteFile & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "quit" & vbCRLF & "quit" & vbCRLF & "quit" & vbCRLF


  sFTPTemp = oFTPScriptShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
  sFTPTempFile = sFTPTemp & "\" & oFTPScriptFSO.GetTempName
  sFTPResults = sFTPTemp & "\" & oFTPScriptFSO.GetTempName

  'Write the input file for the ftp command
  'to a temporary file.
  Set fFTPScript = oFTPScriptFSO.CreateTextFile(sFTPTempFile, True)
  fFTPScript.WriteLine(sFTPScript)
  fFTPScript.Close
  Set fFTPScript = Nothing 

  oFTPScriptShell.Run "%comspec% /c FTP -n -s:" & sFTPTempFile & " " & sSite &  " > " & sFTPResults, 0, TRUE

  Wscript.Sleep 1000

  'Check results of transfer.
  Set fFTPResults = oFTPScriptFSO.OpenTextFile(sFTPResults, ForReading, FailIfNotExist, OpenAsDefault)
  sResults = fFTPResults.ReadAll
  fFTPResults.Close

  'oFTPScriptFSO.DeleteFile(sFTPTempFile)
  'oFTPScriptFSO.DeleteFile (sFTPResults)

  If InStr(sResults, "226 Transfer complete.") > 0 Then
    FTPDownload = True
  ElseIf InStr(sResults, "File not found") > 0 Then
    FTPDownload = "Error: File Not Found"
  ElseIf InStr(sResults, "cannot log in.") > 0 Then
    FTPDownload = "Error: Login Failed."
  Else
    FTPDownload = "Error: Unknown."
  End If

  Set oFTPScriptFSO = Nothing
  Set oFTPScriptShell = Nothing
End Function
```

Hello, I am trying to use this vbs script by naterice.com. It seems working but downloaded files, or file are blank. Any idea? (Windows 2000, IIS6). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that downloads a text file from MS's ftp server and saves it in the c:\user folder.

Run it in a command prompt with cscript to see error messages (both server and local), or change Outp.write to message boxes.

```
cscript "c:\path to script\ftp.vbs"
```

You must specify the url absolutely correctly. There isn't a helper to work out what you mean. Match case on the server path eg README.TXT on the server should also be upper case in your URL.

ADODB is a binary format. The code you had would only work reliably on English computers as windows translates characters for the language used. This code originally downloaded MS's Safety Scanner.

```
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/Softlib/README.TXT", False
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
  Outp.writeline "" 
  Outp.writeline "Error getting file" 
  Outp.writeline "==================" 
  Outp.writeline "" 
  Outp.writeline "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
  Outp.writeline "Source " & err.source 
  Outp.writeline "" 
  Outp.writeline "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
  Outp.writeline  File.getAllResponseHeaders
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\ReadMe.txt", 2
```

Comment: Helklo, tahnks for trying to assist, but there is an error:Line 23
Argument are of the wrong type, are of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another. Code 800A0BB9, source ADODB.stream

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fred for assistance, at the end I have found out that I have got some networks problems with my server. It accepts some traffic but not all... This may explain why the first script by naterice.com has been working at my computer and was not working at the server. The same may be true with your script.

Comment: It is confirmed. My provider changed the router and because of this some of xml scripts stopped to work. But to have a fun - some of them worked, some networks connections did not work, some worked... Now they put back old routing and everything works...