# Remove lines in text files that have "." Batch File

Tags: batch-file, automation

I have a text file that looks like this.

```
/var/www/xxx/html/TEST/VIDEOS/video3.mp4
/var/www/xxx/html/TEST/video_folder_1/cideo.mp4
/var/www/xxx/TEST/video_folder_1/sadasd
/var/www/xxx/html/TEST/video_folder_2/asdsadasdasdsadsadsadsadas
/var/www/xxx/html/TEST/video_folder_2/cideo2.mp4
/var/www/xxx/html/TEST/video_folder_2/sadsada
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
/var/www/xxx/TEST/video_folder_1/sadasd
/var/www/xxx/html/TEST/video_folder_2/asdsadasdasdsadsadsadsadas
/var/www/xxx/html/TEST/video_folder_2/sadsada
```

The idea would be to remove any line that have an extension. I.E mp4 in this case.

So I guess it would look for 4 character in at the end of the line and see if it has a "."

If it does, remove the line.

Comment: `findstr /L /V "." theFile.txt`

Comment: I can get it to work with `findstr /L /V "mp4" theFile.txt` but not when I use `"."`. It does not work.

Comment: Use this as `\.mp4$` as `.` means any character unless escaped with `\ `. Also `$` means end of line. You are in the wrong language. If it feels like you are going against the flow, then you are going against the flow. Programming should be easy, if it's not then your language is wrong or your program design is wrong. VBScript can do files as a console program does AND also do objects (which include files) that appear in folder windows. It is also geared to processing text and data unlike batch which is geared towards processing files of filenames.

Comment: Also does not `Dir /b /s c:\boot` give you your desired end state (based on your other questions).

Comment: @Serenity - `Dir /b /s c:\boot` would not give the desired results as this list is from an FTP using ftp.exe. Effectively a list in a text document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch you should be able to do this in many ways:

```
findstr /V /L "." theFile.txt
```

As Aacini suggests, which checks if the line contains a `.` and works fine when tested.

If you want to user regular expression

```
findstr /V /R "\....$" theFile.txt
```

Which does exactly what you asked for by checking if a line ends with a `.***`

Lastly what I would recommend is using this:

```
findstr /V /R "\.[a-z0-9]*$" theFile.txt
```

which checks if the line ends with any sort of extension, thus including possible 4-letter extensions.

I have tested each of these and they all work fine.

I really don't know why Serenity insists you use VBscript which is no doubt a great language but for a simple thing like this batch is so much more simpler.

Comment: Because he has asked 1000 questions about getting his output right. If you read all of them rather than one intermediate step .... In VBScript he could go through each folder doing what he wants to each file using recursion. It would be a short program. I would have answered that but the specs are spread over 1000 questions. At least he is learning. I like people that want to learn.

Comment: Also he needs to take text from one line and prepend it to others. A **global** regex is better for this which findstr isn't..

Comment: @Serenity, Ok, not quite a 1000 but I know what you mean :). This process I am making is a little complex for me however it is better to break the functionally down, little by little because other people can learn from the small functional parts opposed to the complete solution. However, it goes like this. `Connect to FTP > Download list of dir for certain folder > make txt file (I wanted an array) > take variable which is a file name > search text folder and match variable name > copy ONLY that line in to batch as a new var > us RENAME to move vid to correct folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is a vbs regex replace program. Far more powerful than FindStr. It works globably so you can target line endings.

This is help from a similar line based, not global, program of mine. The point is to show sample RegEx expressions.

To extract all section headers, ie, lines without an equal sign

```
filter filter iv "=" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

To extract all section headers starting with a lower case letter

```
filter filter n "\[[a-z].+" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

This shows the caret escaping an opening bracket for CMD.EXE and the backslash escaping the opening bracket for the RegEx engine

```
filter filter n "\^(" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

This shows searching for a quote character

```
filter filter n "\x22" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

Use $1, $2, $..., $n to specify sub matches in the replace string

```
filter replace i "=" "No equal sign" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

This searches for text within square brackets and replaces the line with cat followed by the text within brackets

```
Filter replace i "^\[^(.*^)\]" "cat$1" < %windir%\win.ini
```

This searches for any text and prints from the 11th character to the end of the line.

```
Filter replace i "^.{10}^(.*^)$" "$1" < %windir%\win.ini
```

This searches a CSV file and prints the second and fourth field

```
Filter replace i "^.+,^(.+^),.+,^(.+^)$" "$1,$2" < csv.txt
```

The script.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ReportErrors "Creating Shell.App"
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ReportErrors "Creating Wscript.Shell"
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
ReportErrors "Creating Wscript.Arg"
Set regEx = New RegExp
ReportErrors "Creating RegEx"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ReportErrors "Creating FSO"

If objArgs.Count = 0 then
        wscript.echo "No parameters", 16, "Serenity's ReplaceRegExp"
        ReportErrors "Help"
ElseIf objArgs.Count = 1 then
        wscript.echo "Only one parameter", 16, "Serenity's ReplaceRegExp"
        ReportErrors "Help"
ElseIf objArgs.Count = 2 then
        Set srcfile = fso.GetFile(objArgs(0))
        ReportErrors "srcFile"
        If err.number = 0 then Set TS = srcFile.OpenAsTextStream(1, 0)
        If err.number <> 0 then
            wscript.echo err.description & " " & srcFile.path, 48, "Serenity's Search" 
            err.clear
        else
            ReportErrors "TS" & "     " & srcFile.path
            Src=ts.readall
            If err.number = 62 then
                err.clear
            else
                ReportErrors "ReadTS" & "     " & srcFile.path
                regEx.Pattern = objArgs(1) 
                regEx.IgnoreCase = True
                regEx.Global = True
                If regEx.Test(Src) = True then
                    wscript.echo "Found in " & srcfile.path, 64, "Serenity's Search" 
                End If
            End If
        End If
        ReportErrors "Check OK" & "     " & srcFile.path

Elseif objArgs.count = 3 then
        Set srcfile = fso.GetFile(objArgs(0))
        ReportErrors "srcFile"
        If err.number = 0 then Set TS = srcFile.OpenAsTextStream(1, 0)
        If err.number <> 0 then
            wscript.echo err.description & " " & srcFile.path, 48, "Serenity's Search" 
            err.clear
        else
            ReportErrors "TS" & "     " & srcFile.path
            Src=ts.readall
            If err.number = 62 then
                err.clear
            else
                ReportErrors "ReadTS" & "     " & srcFile.path
                regEx.Pattern = objArgs(1) 
                regEx.IgnoreCase = True
                regEx.Global = True
                NewSrc= regEx.Replace(Src, objArgs(2)) 
                If NewSrc<>Src then
                    wscript.echo "Replacement made in " & srcfile.path, 64, "Serenity's Search" 
                    TS.close
                    Set TS = srcFile.OpenAsTextStream(2, 0)
                    ts.write newsrc
                    ReportErrors "Writing file"
                End If
            End If
        End If
        ReportErrors "Check OK" & "     " & srcFile.path


Else
        wscript.echo "Too many parameters", 16, "Serenity's ReplaceRegExp"
        ReportErrors "Help"

ReportErrors "All Others"
End If

Sub ReportErrors(strModuleName)
    If err.number<>0 then wscript.echo "An unexpected error occurred. This dialog provides details on the error." & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "Error Details " & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "Script Name" & vbTab & Wscript.ScriptFullName & vbCRLF & "Module" & vbtab & vbTab & strModuleName & vbCRLF & "Error Number" & vbTab & err.number & vbCRLF & "Description" & vbTab & err.description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Something unexpected"
    Err.clear
End Sub
```

**RegEx Reference**

Regular Expressions Reference

From the Windows Vista SDK, VBScript Language Reference © Microsoft Corp 2006

```
Character Description 
\ Marks the next character as either a special character or a literal. For example, "n" matches the character "n". "\n" matches a newline character. The sequence "\\" matches "\" and "\(" matches "(". 
^ Matches the beginning of input. 
$ Matches the end of input. 
* Matches the preceding character zero or more times. For example, "zo*" matches either "z" or "zoo". 
+ Matches the preceding character one or more times. For example, "zo+" matches "zoo" but not "z". 
? Matches the preceding character zero or one time. For example, "a?ve?" matches the "ve" in "never". 
. Matches any single character except a newline character. 
(pattern) Matches pattern and remembers the match. The matched substring can be retrieved from the resulting Matches collection, using Item [0]...[n]. To match parentheses characters ( ), use "\(" or "\)". 
x|y Matches either x or y. For example, "z|wood" matches "z" or "wood". "(z|w)oo" matches "zoo" or "wood". 
{n} n is a nonnegative integer. Matches exactly n times. For example, "o{2}" does not match the "o" in "Bob," but matches the first two o's in "foooood". 
{n,} n is a nonnegative integer. Matches at least n times. For example, "o{2,}" does not match the "o" in "Bob" and matches all the o's in "foooood." "o{1,}" is equivalent to "o+". "o{0,}" is equivalent to "o*". 
{ n , m } m and n are nonnegative integers. Matches at least n and at most m times. For example, "o{1,3}" matches the first three o's in "fooooood." "o{0,1}" is equivalent to "o?". 
[ xyz ] A character set. Matches any one of the enclosed characters. For example, "[abc]" matches the "a" in "plain". 
[^ xyz ] A negative character set. Matches any character not enclosed. For example, "[^abc]" matches the "p" in "plain". 
[ a-z ] A range of characters. Matches any character in the specified range. For example, "[a-z]" matches any lowercase alphabetic character in the range "a" through "z". 
[^ m-z ] A negative range characters. Matches any character not in the specified range. For example, "[m-z]" matches any character not in the range "m" through "z". 
\b Matches a word boundary, that is, the position between a word and a space. For example, "er\b" matches the "er" in "never" but not the "er" in "verb". 
\B Matches a non-word boundary. "ea*r\B" matches the "ear" in "never early". 
\d Matches a digit character. Equivalent to [0-9]. 
\D Matches a non-digit character. Equivalent to [^0-9]. 
\f Matches a form-feed character. 
\n Matches a newline character. 
\r Matches a carriage return character. 
\s Matches any white space including space, tab, form-feed, etc. Equivalent to "[ \f\n\r\t\v]". 
\S Matches any nonwhite space character. Equivalent to "[^ \f\n\r\t\v]". 
\t Matches a tab character. 
\v Matches a vertical tab character. 
\w Matches any word character including underscore. Equivalent to "[A-Za-z0-9_]". 
\W Matches any non-word character. Equivalent to "[^A-Za-z0-9_]". 
\num Matches num, where num is a positive integer. A reference back to remembered matches. For example, "(.)\1" matches two consecutive identical characters. 
\ n Matches n, where n is an octal escape value. Octal escape values must be 1, 2, or 3 digits long. For example, "\11" and "\011" both match a tab character. "\0011" is the equivalent of "\001" & "1". Octal escape values must not exceed 256. If they do, only the first two digits comprise the expression. Allows ASCII codes to be used in regular expressions. 
\xn Matches n, where n is a hexadecimal escape value. Hexadecimal escape values must be exactly two digits long. For example, "\x41" matches "A". "\x041" is equivalent to "\x04" & "1". Allows ASCII codes to be used in regular expressions. 
Go to top of page
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I give this a go however VB is not my fort, nevertheless, it is a great way to improve.

Comment: Your problem is one that can be solved in several ways. Using GLOBAL regex you can search for a line of text, remember that line, and insert it elsewhere. Also using a VBScript I can get this from ftp.microsoft.com

Comment: `...html headers ommitted... <H2 ID="WinINetFtpDirectory">FTP directory /Softlib/ at ftp.microsoft.com</H2>
<HR>
<H4><PRE>
Welcome to FTP.MICROSOFT.COM. Also visit http://www.microsoft.com/downloads.
</PRE></H4>
<HR>
<A HREF="..">Up to higher level directory</A><BR><PRE>
05/10/2000 12:48PM        205,710 <A HREF="/Softlib/index.txt">index.txt</A>
04/30/2010 10:10AM      Directory <A HREF="/Softlib/MSLFILES/"><B>MSLFILES</B></A>
09/03/1999 01:03PM          2,401 <A HREF="/Softlib/README.TXT">README.TXT</A>
</PRE>
` So you can load and go through the anchor collection.

Comment: The script is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584898/wscript-ftp-download-error To get a directory list web page just ask for a folder rather than a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate lines with "." from the output created in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583417/using-batch-to-clean-up-file-names-to-name-full-path), then a much simpler solution is to insert a test in that code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   if "!line:~0,1!" equ "/" (
      set "header=%%a"
   ) else (
      if "!line:.=!" equ "!line!" echo !header:~0,-1!/%%a
   )
)) > testnew.txt
```